# J2ObjC: translating @Nullable to __nullable

Tags: java, objective-c, swift, j2objc

I'm trying to translate Java nullability annotations to Objective-C to get Optionals in Swift but nothing happens, the signature of the methods remains the same.

Here is the Java code:

```
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import com.google.j2objc.annotations.ObjectiveCName;

public class UserValidation {
    @Nullable
    @ObjectiveCName(value = "getFormattedUserId:")
    public static String getFormattedUserId(@Nullable String userId) {}
}
```

When traslated I get:

```
+ (NSString *)getFormattedUserId:(NSString *)userId;
```

instead of:

```
+ (NSString * __nullable)getFormattedUserId:(NSString * __nullable)userId;
```

I want this signature sin Swift:

```
class func getFormattedUserId(userId: String?) -> String?
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much.

Comment: How exactly are you doing the translating? Presumably some program ... surely this program has options and configuration? Maybe you should tell us a bit more about what you're doing.

Comment: j2objc, sorry, I put the tag but nothing more. I edit the question.

Comment: Didn't include the --nullability flag? Or maybe looking at the .m file instead of the header?

    $ j2objc -q -classpath ~/jars/jsr305.jar --nullability UserValidation.java
    $ grep nullable UserValidation.h
    + (NSString * __nullable)getFormattedUserId:(NSString * __nullable)userId;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the comment by @tball is correct, it worked adding the `--nullability` flag, with the latest sources, not the latest release.

More information [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/j2objc-discuss/Bp98Jqbohuo).

Thanks Tom.